# ReferenceError: chunks is not defined

Tags: javascript

The following code tries to injuect some code into an iFrame (on the same server as the page). I am getting a **ReferenceError: chunks is not defined** error. Can somebody help me figure out why please? I've been baning my head on this one for a day now.

```
<iframe id="preview-iframe"></iframe>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var chunks;
chunks += "<span class=\"bold";
chunks += "\">Hello World!</";
chunks += "span>";
document.getElementById("preview-iframe").src="javascript:void(document.write(chunks))";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe id="prev-frame"></iframe>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var chunks = '';
    chunks += "<span class=\"bold";
    chunks += "\">Hello World!</";
    chunks += "span>";
    document.getElementById("prev-frame").src="javascript:void(document.write('" + chunks + "'))";
</script>
```

You need to concatanate `'" + chunks + "'` so that it is not interpreted literally. Also, `iframe` is a reserved word so I renamed the `id` on the frame.

:)

Comment: this is why i like stackoverflow so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the scope of the iFrame is different to the original doc, this may help: [passing in javascript values into iframe tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625615/passing-in-javascript-values-into-iframe-tag)

I'd also set chunks to an empty string when you declare it...

```
var chunks = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("preview-iframe").contentWindow.document.write(chunks);​
```

Should work. As Rob W said the iframe does not share the same scope as your page.